# Joomla 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

One of my website developed using joomla..actually it was an old version( Version 1.5).it was running successfully but now its showing 403 Forbidden error.

My htaccess file look like these

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]


RewriteBase /



RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: If the behavior changed and the htaccess didn't then most likely something in the environment changed.  For example did the PHP version or apache version change?

Comment: i contacted the hosting team and they are telling its due to the virus.can you telll me how can i  fix the files from viruses.

Comment: The Joomla documentation site has advice about what to do if you have been hacked. https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

Answer (score 0):

If you have a virus on your Joomla website then the first thing that you will need to know is to discover where. It doesn't seem to be in the .htaccess file so you will need to look elsewhere. Try running maldet on your website (or ask your host to run maldet for you) and tell you which files are infected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this issue, but your question came up in my search when I encountered a similar scenario. My htaccess file was alright, and I could not trace out any hacked files. What saved the day was Googling the error from the site error log:

> joomla 1.5 Permission denied:...public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile:
>   unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

The search results led me to [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PcfgOpenfile). By following the advice there I noticed that the site's public_html permissions had been changed from the default 755 to 750. Changing it back to 755 sorted the issue out instantly.
I'm still checking for any signs of hacking but for now, the site is up and running again, and the client is happy.
Hope this helps someone else out there...